# Graphical representation of HTML table data using High charts

Tags: html, highcharts, html-table

I am trying to display the data in HTML table in graphical form using High Charts. When I use all the data from the table I am able to render the charts. I want to use only  some part of data from my table (some columns data) to render a chart. Can anyone please tell me how  to do this. If you have snippets please provide them. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you just iterate over the table and select the data / columns required either into a 2d array or another dynamically created table? You can then get Highcharts to use your filtered datasource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do the same using Fusion charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 'docs' are included inline to the data.src.js module:

- http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js

For now only startRow/endRow/startColumn/endColumn options are supported:

> table : String|HTMLElement
>
> A HTML table or the id of such to be parsed as input data. Related options ara startRow, endRow, startColumn and endColumn to delimit what part of the table is used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do the same using Fusion charts

Comment: I have no idea, sorry :)